# Synthesis of an epoxide from 1,2-diol

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, synthesis

[image: 1,2-diol + SOCl2]

Why is there no formation of epoxide when the two OH-groups are on different planes? I do understand the epoxidation mechanism. However, I would be grateful if someone cleared the specific requirements for epoxidation.

Comment: Read up on under what conditions SOCl2 reacts with ROH to give RCl. One set of conditions is SN2; another "internal return", i.e., no inversion.

Comment: In the above mechanism base is seen at the second step which is not the case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thionyl chloride first reacts with the alcohol to form an alkyl chloro sulfite,which gives various stereochemical products as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNi).

[image]

Extending this to the current question , alkyl chloro sulfite **2** is formed.${Cl^-}$ attacks in a ${S_N^2}$ mode to give **3**.

Base deprotonates **3** to give **4**.

Alkoxide and chloride in **4** are in correct trans configuration for a ${S_N^2}$.This results in **5**(**B in your scheme**).

[image]

If we take **C** in your question , and follow the scheme above, **9**  is formed.In **9** alkoxide and chloride are not in correct configuration for ${S_N^2}$.Therefore 
**C** in your question does not undergo epoxidation.

[image]

Comment: Detailed answer but the OP didn't make much of an effort. That is why I offered hints and no answer. Respectfully, I think we should refrain from quickly offering answers when little effort is made by the OP and hints are offered in the comments. Let the OP do some work.

Comment: @user55119 ,noted,the question was intreasting for an answer.